# php json_encode with custom keys

Tags: php, json

I am creating JSON string using PHP to represent directory structure and then render it as tree view, the tree view control am using requires to add a "text" key for every directory/file name, and a "nodes" key for every sub directories/files, so am using the following code which create an array with sub arrays then am using json_encode to convert the array to JSON format, so can json_encode format the output to have the required keys "text/nodes"?

here is the code am using

```
echo json_encode(ReadFolderDirectory('some directory'));
function ReadFolderDirectory($dir,$listDir= array())
{
$listDir = array();
if($handler = opendir($dir))
{
    while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if ($sub != "." && $sub != ".." && $sub != "Thumb.db")
        {
            if(is_file($dir."/".$sub))
            {
                $listDir[] = $sub;
            }elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$sub))
            {
                $listDir[$sub] = ReadFolderDirectory($dir."/".$sub); 
            } 
        } 
    }    
    closedir($handler); 
} 
return $listDir;    
}
```

the control am using is here and the JSON data should look like as in their data structure section: https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview#data-structure

Comment: What are you asking? Whether you can include certain keys with certain values? Yes? `array('foo' => 'bar')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo json_encode(ReadFolderDirectory('some directory'));
function ReadFolderDirectory($dir,$listDir= array())
{
$listDir = array();
if($handler = opendir($dir))
{
    while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if ($sub != "." && $sub != ".." && $sub != "Thumb.db")
        {
            $obj = new stdClass();
            $obj->text = $sub;
            if(is_dir($dir."/".$sub))
            {
                $obj->nodes = ReadFolderDirectory($dir."/".$sub);
            } 
            $listDir[] = $obj;
        } 
    }    
    closedir($handler); 
} 
return $listDir;    
}
```